# Prevent java from localizing SimpleDateFormat output

Tags: java, date, localization, format

Basicaly I want to format a Date object using a specific pattern and the output should be in English. How can I prevent java from translating the output in the system language?

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss yyyy").format(myDate);
// output is in German:
// Mi Aug 26 16:35:55 2009
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat` is always localized, it makes no sense otherwise.

You can, however, specify the Locale to use when you build it, e.g.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
   "EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss yyyy", 
   Locale.ENGLISH
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I have to pass a timestamp to a remote server, that's why I needed "unlocalized" output.

Comment: In that case, I suggest passing in ISO-standard format. JodaTime's ISODateTimeFormat performs that task nicely.